# Ball to brick collision in c#

Tags: c#, drawing, drawrectangle

I am writing a program that has a ball moving around a PictureBox and I have a set of bricks at the top of the PictureBox.

I have used an array for location of the bricks that I will be using:

```
int[,] brickLocation = { { 0, 0 }, { 30, 0 } }
```

I have used the DrawRectangle to construct each brick within the picturebox. This exist within timer1_Tick event. As the ball is drawn, then the picturebox is cleared and the x and y coordinate change.

When the ball "collides" with the brick, I want some way in which the brick will disappear because there will be another brick behind it.

[brick0]

[brick1]

At the moment, my code for the collision between the ball and brick1 is:

```
if ((yBall > brickY) && (yBall < brickY + 25) && (xBall > brickX) && (xBall < brickX + 80))
            {
                yBallChange = -yBallChange;
            }
```

where xBall, yBall is the x and y coordinate of the ball and brickX and brickY are the coordinate for the bricks.

So when the ball coordinates are within the bounds of brick1 the y-direction will change.

Is there some way in which I can redraw [brick1] in a new position with no size as to eliminate it so there can then be a collision between the ball and [brick0]?
Or is there something else I could do?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543096/delete-rectangle-using-net

Comment: You can't just erase the brick and set a flag to say that the brick is no longer active?

Comment: As @JimMischel said, just don't draw the brick. Set a flag and don't draw the bricks or do collision check against them based on that flag. I recommend creating a `Brick` class to house coordinates and information related to it instead of just an array of int coordinates.

Comment: The task requires me to use a array for the coordinates of the bricks as I going to add more. I could set a timer that draws each brick and when the collision occurs that timer for that brick would stop, so the brick1 would no longer be drawn and a collision between brick0 and the ball could take place.